# Transposing a python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, transpose

I have a list of columns that I am trying to show as multiple columns:

Given below is the list:

```
for name in file:
    worksheet.write(row, col, name)
    col += 1
```

Given below is the output created:

```
['apples','oranges','bananas','pears']
```

I am trying to transpose it and have it displayed as below :

```
apples
oranges
bananas
pears
```

Could anyone advice how could I get my list transposed. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the col increment to row increment will solve your problem.

```
for name in file:
    worksheet.write(row, col, name)
    row += 1
```

Output:

```
apples
oranges
bananas
pears
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm getting it right you want this:

```
[list(item) for item in your_list]
```

This will create a 2d list, each item of which in it's own 'row'.

Answer (score 0):

Use `join`:

```
print('\n'.join(your_list))
```

`join` can do what you want.

Output:

```
apples
oranges
bananas
pears
```

Comment: tried the above but it still displays each of the items in the list in separate columns but does not transpose it by row..

Comment: @hellokee What's the desired output then?

Comment: I am trying to have these values displayed in different rows but same column.. I am not sure if I am expressing how I want. If you refer to the expected output I shared in my initial message, each of the items of the list are displayed one below the other but in the same column.. hope this helps.. Tnx

Comment: @hellokee Doesn't mine do that? can you please run it again?